# How to display data of an entity in modal with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

i display some model entities with ng-repeat like and add a twitter bootstrap modal. The modal contains a form:

```
<div class="entity" ng-repeat="entity in model" ng-click="openModal()">
  <b>{{ model.title }}</b></br>
  <i>{{ model.content }}</i>
</div>
<!-- bootstrap modal ... -->
<div id="modal" ....
```

What is the best practise to open a bootstrap modal (which contain a form), and display the data of the entity in the form?

Comment: You can use http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, pay attention that you have a bug in the example (entity.title not model.title).

As for the modal, you can create a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) called modal-window and pass the entity to it.

You can pass the entity through the openModal(entity), and have the modal window bind a property to it.

Something like

**Controller:**

```
$scope.entity = {};
$scope.showModal = false;

$scope.openModal = function( entity ){
  $scope.entity = entity;
  $scope.showModal = true;
}
```

**template:**

`<modal-window entity="entity"></modal-window>`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Do you mean like on that page:  http://www.grobmeier.de/twitter-bootstrap-modal-angular-js-29082012.html#.UQe26r--nQd .

Comment: @Valentyn - just saw you post it too... :)